# How to generate transformed web.config files using post build command

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, web-config, web.config-transform

How to add PostBuild commands for the web.config xdt transformation so that when a build is queued successfully it will transform the web.config as per the web.platform.config xdt commands.

If the build branch is e.g. OnlineManagement_Dev then the transformation should happen based on the web.debug.config when I queue this branch . 
If the build branch is e.g. OnlineManagement_UAT then the transformation should happen based on the web.UAT.config when I queue this branch . 
If the build branch is e.g. OnlineManagement_PROD then the transformation should happen based on the web.PROD.config  when I queue this branch .

I tried looking at the below solution but looks like 'TransformXml' task has a file lock bug. Is there any update to the MSBuild which provides a simpler and better solution than this ?

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/09/14/using-custom-webconfig-transformations-in-msbuild

Answer (score 2):

1) The FileLock "bug" is addressed in the code sample in the section where they explain the bug  before including the work around.

2) Do you have an environment variable and/or an MsBuild property that contains the branch type?  If so, simply use that to determine source.

e.g.

```
<TransformXml Source="web.UAT.config"
  Transform="TransformFile.config"
  Destination="Web.config"
  StackTrace="true" />
```

Update the Source using the name of the environment variable or MSBuild Property that contains this value.

```
<TransformXml Source="web.$(EnvironmentType).config"
  Transform="TransformFile.config"
  Destination="Web.config"
  StackTrace="true" />
```

Note that if you are building from a command prompt and already have this in an environment variable, wrap the ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME like this $(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME), and MsBuild will identify it.

Comment: I always queue the build from the Team Explorer. And I see the build definition has some variables. Are you talking about the varibles in the description of Build definition ? I think its a good idea to add a variable in the build definition rather than in the .cs proj because when code gets merged to UAT / PROD branch then we don't have to worry about this environment variable . Isn't it ?

Comment: Try building this with logging set to "debug" verbosity.  When you do this, the MsBuild log with have a very lengthy preamble containing a list of all environment variables as well as any MsBuild properties and their values.